# Add shadow to UITableView inside a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, calayer, shadow

I have added shadow in `viewDidLoad`, but it does not appeared. `UINavigationController` `clip to bound` is set to false, but still shadow is clipped. Do you know why, how to render shadow?

```
tableview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: -10)
tableview.layer.shadowRadius = 10
tableview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
tableview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
tableview.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the table ?

Comment: Try in viewDidAppear

Comment: try setting tableview clipsToBounds = false;